# How to display a message when all columns values are null

Tags: sql, oracle, coalesce

```
SELECT  NVL(T1.C1, 'NO RECORDS'), T1.C2, T2.C3, T1.C4  

FROM TEMP T1, TEMP_1 T2

WHERE
  T1.C2 = T2.C2
  AND T1 IN ( 'T001','T002')

  ;
```

I'm getting all null values for the columns, what can I do to display a message, I tried using Coalesce it did not work properly. NVL function does not return the desired result as well.
Need some help

Comment: what is your database?

Answer (score 1):

We don't know the database you use but something like the following should work for you :

```
SELECT COALESCE(T1.C1,T1.C2,T2.C3,T1.C4 'NO RECORDS')
FROM TEMP T1, TEMP_1 T2
WHERE T1.C2 = T2.C2 AND T1 IN ( 'T001','T002')
```

The coalesce get a variable numbers of arguments and returns the first non-null :

```
COALESCE( expr1, expr2, ... expr_n )
```

so in you case if you get 'NO RECORDS' mans that all the 4 field are null ...

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the problem is that you have no rows. When you return a row with a `null` column, `coalesce` or `nvl` will do exactly what you expect. If you need to return a value when when the result set is empty, you need to use a bit more trickery. You can do that like this:

```
SELECT NVL (t1.c1, 'NO RECORDS'),
       t1.c2,
       t2.c3,
       t1.c4
FROM   temp t1, temp_1 t2
WHERE  t1.c2 = t2.c2 AND t1 IN ('T001', 'T002')
UNION ALL
SELECT 'NO_RECORDS',
       NULL,
       NULL,
       NULL
FROM   DUAL
WHERE  NOT EXISTS
          (SELECT *
           FROM   temp t1, temp_1 t2
           WHERE  t1.c2 = t2.c2 AND t1 IN ('T001', 'T002'));
```

However, if this is intended to be interpreted by code somewhere, you'd be better off determining that no rows were returned via the available metadata rather than from a magic value.

If c1 is a number or date, then you'll need to use either `CAST` or `TO_CHAR` to convert it to a varchar2 in order to make this work. Queries merged via `UNION` must have the same data type for each column.

Comment: yes, u r right, I've no rows and that's the expected result of my query. However; I've to display "No Recods Found" in this case. I tried using your trick but it throws error message,"expression must have same datatype as corresponding expression"

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try using CASE ?

```
SELECT CASE 
        WHEN T1.C1 IS NULL
            THEN 'NO RECORDS'
        ELSE T1.C1
        END,
    T1.C2,
    T2.C3,
    T1.C4
FROM TEMP T1
INNER JOIN TEMP_1 T2
    ON T1.C2 = T2.C2
WHERE T1 IN (
        'T001',
        'T002'
        );
```

Also, not sure if I understand this statement `T1 IN ( 'T001','T002')`

Answer (score 0):

I assume because of your use of the `NVL()` function that you're using Oracle. I also noticed from your comments that you are not trying to find rows where all columns are `NULL` but rather find records in one table for which there are no corresponding records in another table. That can be done in a couple of ways, one, using `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT t1.c1
  FROM t1
 WHERE t1.c1 IN ('T001','T002')
   AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM t2
                     WHERE t2.c2 = t1.c1 );
```

or you could use an outer join:

```
-- ANSI syntax
SELECT t1.c1
  FROM t1 LEFT JOIN t2
    ON t1.c1 = t2.c2
 WHERE t1.c1 IN ('T001','T002')
   AND t2.c2 IS NULL;

-- Old Oracle syntax
SELECT t1.c1
  FROM t1, t2
 WHERE t1.c1 IN ('T001','T002')
   AND t1.c1 = t2.c2(+)
   AND t2.c2 IS NULL;
```